# What is the best way to extract embedded flash file from a PDF using the PDFBox parser?

Tags: java, eclipse, parsing, pdf, pdfbox

I've been working around PDF parsing since late last week. Managed to find the Apache PDFBox library for Java and I already got to extract text separated by page, URLs, images and PDF Metadata that I needed for the project I'm developing. Now I'm missing a way to extract embedded flash videos from a PDF.

I'm currently analysing how this parser extracts rich media from PDFs, using, for test purposes the pdf file available [here](http://www.pdfpictures.com/download.php?name=Mississauga_Advantages.pdf). This file contains a flash video which I intended to fetch.

I already tried using this [approach](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/pdmodel/ExtractEmbeddedFiles.java?view=markup) which searches for embedded files inside the PDF but it is currently not working for me as it finds and saves nothing inside the folder I created to store this kind of files.

What my code currently looks like, adapted from the approach mentioned above.

```
package myproject;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocumentNameDictionary;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDEmbeddedFilesNameTreeNode;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.common.PDNameTreeNode;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.common.filespecification.PDComplexFileSpecification;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.common.filespecification.PDEmbeddedFile;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.annotation.PDAnnotation;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.annotation.PDAnnotationFileAttachment;

/**
 * This is an example on how to extract all embedded files from a PDF document.
 *
 */
public final class ExtractEmbeddedFiles
{
    private ExtractEmbeddedFiles()
    {
    }

    /**
     * This is the main method.
     *
     * @param args The command line arguments.
     *
     * @throws IOException If there is an error parsing the document.
     */
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException
    {
            PDDocument document = null;
            try
            {
                File pdfFile = new File("/Users/henriqueferreira/Documents/PDFBoxDocuments/inOntario.pdf");
                String filePath = pdfFile.getParent() + System.getProperty("file.separator");
                document = PDDocument.load(new File("/Users/henriqueferreira/Documents/PDFBoxDocuments/inOntario.pdf"));
                PDDocumentNameDictionary namesDictionary = 
                        new PDDocumentNameDictionary( document.getDocumentCatalog() );
                PDEmbeddedFilesNameTreeNode efTree = namesDictionary.getEmbeddedFiles();
                if (efTree != null)
                {
                    Map<String, PDComplexFileSpecification> names = efTree.getNames();
                    if (names != null)
                    {
                        extractFiles(names, filePath);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        List<PDNameTreeNode<PDComplexFileSpecification>> kids = efTree.getKids();
                        for (PDNameTreeNode<PDComplexFileSpecification> node : kids)
                        {
                            names = node.getNames();
                            extractFiles(names, filePath);
                        }
                    }
                }

                // extract files from annotations
                for (PDPage page : document.getPages())
                {
                    for (PDAnnotation annotation : page.getAnnotations())
                    {
                        if (annotation instanceof PDAnnotationFileAttachment)
                        {
                            PDAnnotationFileAttachment annotationFileAttachment = (PDAnnotationFileAttachment) annotation;
                            PDComplexFileSpecification fileSpec = (PDComplexFileSpecification) annotationFileAttachment.getFile();
                            PDEmbeddedFile embeddedFile = getEmbeddedFile(fileSpec);
                            extractFile(filePath, fileSpec.getFilename(), embeddedFile);
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
            finally
            {
                if( document != null )
                {
                    document.close();
                }
            }
    }

    private static void extractFiles(Map<String, PDComplexFileSpecification> names, String filePath) 
            throws IOException
    {
        for (Entry<String, PDComplexFileSpecification> entry : names.entrySet())
        {
            String filename = entry.getKey();
            PDComplexFileSpecification fileSpec = entry.getValue();
            PDEmbeddedFile embeddedFile = getEmbeddedFile(fileSpec);
            extractFile(filePath, filename, embeddedFile);
        }
    }

    private static void extractFile(String filePath, String filename, PDEmbeddedFile embeddedFile)
            throws IOException
    {
        String embeddedFilename = filePath + filename;
        File file = new File("/Users/henriqueferreira/Documents/PDFBoxFiles/"+filename);
        System.out.println("Writing " + embeddedFilename);
        try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file))
        {
            fos.write(embeddedFile.toByteArray());
        }
    }

    private static PDEmbeddedFile getEmbeddedFile(PDComplexFileSpecification fileSpec )
    {
        // search for the first available alternative of the embedded file
        PDEmbeddedFile embeddedFile = null;
        if (fileSpec != null)
        {
            embeddedFile = fileSpec.getEmbeddedFileUnicode(); 
            if (embeddedFile == null)
            {
                embeddedFile = fileSpec.getEmbeddedFileDos();
            }
            if (embeddedFile == null)
            {
                embeddedFile = fileSpec.getEmbeddedFileMac();
            }
            if (embeddedFile == null)
            {
                embeddedFile = fileSpec.getEmbeddedFileUnix();
            }
            if (embeddedFile == null)
            {
                embeddedFile = fileSpec.getEmbeddedFile();
            }
        }
        return embeddedFile;
    }
}
```

So, my question is, what should be the most appropriate method to get this type of flash videos from a PDF file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some quick code based on what I saw with PDFDebugger:

[image]

```
PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(new File("Mississauga_Advantages.pdf"));
for (int p = 0; p < doc.getNumberOfPages(); ++p)
{
    PDPage page = doc.getPage(p);
    List<PDAnnotation> annotations = page.getAnnotations();
    for (PDAnnotation ann : annotations)
    {
        if ("RichMedia".equals(ann.getSubtype()))
        {
            COSArray array = (COSArray) ann.getCOSObject().getObjectFromPath("RichMediaContent/Assets/Names/");
            String name = array.getString(0);
            COSDictionary filespec = (COSDictionary) array.getObject(1);
            PDComplexFileSpecification cfs = new PDComplexFileSpecification(filespec);
            PDEmbeddedFile embeddedFile = cfs.getEmbeddedFile();
            System.out.println("page: " + (p+1) + ", name: " + name + ", size: " + embeddedFile.createInputStream().available());
        }
    }
}
```

Your rich media is in an annotation. So I went through the list and looked for the pattern that I saw. I don't know if this is standard or not, I didn't find it in the PDF 32000 specification. (Update: I found it [here](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/adobe_supplement_iso32000.pdf) after writing the code)

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked. Now I just need to save the files it finds and it is pretty much done.